# Set up java sources for eclipse debugger

Tags: eclipse, debugging

you sure know the situation during debugging when the thread of execution suddenly isn't backed by source code and the icon "attach sources" appears... I can't find any settings where it could be set up. I always have to wait till the previously mentioned situation happens to set it up.

Is there this configuration anywhere in preferences ? I really can't find it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Right click on a project -> Build Path -> Libraries, look here: [Is there an easy way to attach source in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122160/is-there-an-easy-way-to-attach-source-in-eclipse)

Comment: I'm talking about sources for debugging...eclipse debugger has access to the sources attached as you say + to the additional ones that you may attach independently ....If you are remotely debugging app/web server, it has tons of libraries that you don't define in a project, that's why you can't even attach sources to them

Comment: I don't think you can. See for example - note it's a bit outdated, so it might not be correct- http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg61517.html. However, nothing stops you doing exactly what Eric suggests in the post from the previous link - just add all the libraries locally to the project, either one-by-one or, probably much better, as a shared library.

Comment: I know, but I would spend more time playing with eclipse than programming if I did it this way. I leave this question open, maybe somebody knows how to do it, otherwise I'd fill a feature request in eclipse.org, thank you

Comment: Agree with the rest, but unless you have a very strange setup (e.g. multiple application servers or so) IMHO time-wise it's 10 minutes, all with a coffee break. :)