# How do you set the maven artifact ID of a Gradle project?

Tags: maven, gradle, maven-publish

From the gradle [maven-publish plugin's documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html), it's clear that you set the `groupId` and `version` of the project directly in `build.gradle`:

```
group = 'org.gradle.sample'
version = '1.0'
```

However, the `artifactId` appears to be taken from the name of the folder you are working within.  Is there a way to set the `artifactId` explicitly?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

From [36.2.3. Identity values in the generated POM](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#sec:identity_values_in_the_generated_pom)

```
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'org.gradle.sample'
            artifactId 'project1-sample'
            version '1.1'

            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

The artifact ID defaults to the project name configured in `settings.gradle`, which in turn defaults to the project directory's name.

You'll need the appropriate plugin.

```
plugins {
    id 'maven-publish'
}
```

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the response.  Looking at the documentation I've linked to, which is also 65.4, we obviously have different versions of the doc.

Comment: Ah, it's in 65.2.3 of the 2.0 doc.  My comprehension skills are obviously poor; I don't know how I missed this when searching the page for 'artifact' - apologies.

Comment: It's *example* 65.4 in the chapter you linked to.

Comment: Haha well I would, but I'd quite like to set the project name properly, rather than overriding it for `MavenPublication`, and somehow I'm struggling with that.

Comment: If you want to change the project name (which is kind of a separate question), you can do so in `settings.gradle` (e.g. `rootProject.name = "something"`).

Comment: make sure you have  ```plugin: 'maven-publish'``` otherwise you will get `Could not find method publishing()`

Comment: Important: Setting the project name in settings.gradle (e.g. rootProject.name = "org.myorg.myproject") was critical to fixing problems where Jenkins build was uploading to a groupId based defaulting to Jenkins workspace folder name.

Answer (score 23):

Related to the root `settings.gradle` file, you can change the name of the root project with:

```
rootProject.name = 'myproject'
```

But if you want to change the name of a sub-project (for example, the default "app" sub-project of an AndroidStudio project), you can do something like this, still in the root `settings.gradle` file:

```
rootProject.children.each {
    it.name = ('app' == it.name ? 'MyAppName' : it.name)
}
```

Comment: As mentioned by @FarrukhNajmi in a comment, adding the rootProject.name in the settings.gradle file stops the artifactID becoming the Jenkins job name when building with Jenkins.

Answer (score 9):

This is the correct answer for the **maven-publish** plugin. This is intended as the successor for the older **maven** plugin.

If, as I am, you are stuck with the older plugin, the correct answer to "How do I set the maven artifact id for a gradle project" is:

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            pom.artifactId = 'project-sample'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. Doing it here means that any dependencies you have declared against the project relatively from elsewhere will not get the correct artifactId when a pom is generated for them.

Comment: I don't recall this being true (it has been 18 months since I dealt with this) but if so the correct answer is to upgrade your maven plugin to the new one with the better model. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

If you have a multi-module project, and you want the artifacts' names to differ from the Directory (which is set in the settings.gradle), then I think a better approach is to have a jar block for each sub-project, and there you can write the baseName, which will be the artifact-id. Then, *rather than re-writing the publishing/publications block for each sub-project,* you write it only once in the main build.gradle this way:

for each sub-project build.gradle:

```
jar {
    baseName = 'new-artifact-name-A'  //A beacause you also have B, C modules... 
}
```

in the main build.gradle:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
           artifactId jar.baseName
           from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could not find method jar() for arguments

Answer (score 3):

For building android and publishing to artifactory using jenkins, I configured the settings below in the app modules's **build.gradle** for configuring group id, artifact id, and version.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    group "com.company.division.productgroup" //add group id
    version "8.8.8" //add version

    defaultConfig {

        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 32
        versionName "$version"
        archivesBaseName = "android-appname" //add artifact id

    }
```

Comment: archivesBaseName  no effect

Comment: In more recent versions of Gradle/Android, I'm finding that there is a setArchivesBaseName() method provided by BasePluginConvention that is available in place of direct assignment, and it works for me on Android Gradle plugin 3.1.4 and Gradle 4.10.2.  https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/BasePluginConvention.html

Answer (score 2):

In **Gradle**, you can set `jar.archiveName` to override the use of the working folder's name...

```
group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
jar.archiveName = "myproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
```

Comment: jar.archiveName is deprecated as well as jar.baseName

Answer (score 2):

> However, the artifactId appears to be taken from the name of the folder you are working within. Is there a way to set the artifactId explicitly?

A simple answer to this is to set the `jar.baseName` which then overrides the directory name.

```
// changes the name of the jar from the directory name
jar.baseName = 'some_arifact_name';
```

This seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did that for [my Android library](https://github.com/mahozad/android-pie-chart). The solution is in [Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.kts):

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("maven-publish")
    // ...
}

afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            create<MavenPublication>("Release") {
                // ...
                groupId = "ir.mahozad.android"
                artifactId = "pie-chart"
                version = project.version.toString()
                artifact(sourcesArtifact)
                artifact(javadocArtifact)
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can see the [complete build script file here](https://github.com/mahozad/android-pie-chart/blob/169f4591977cb4df9857919ca0d9b1aea2cc7f62/piechart/build.gradle.kts).

See a [similar answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70859560/8583692).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a conditional to change your artifactId as well.

```
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {

            //adding conditional
            artifactId = artifactId == 'original-name' ? 'my-specific-name' : artifactId

            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```

Also you can add a switch if you have many project names to change.

```
publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {

            //adding switch
            switch(artifactId) {
                case 'first-project-original-name':
                    artifactId = 'my-first-specific-name'
                    break
                case 'second-project-original-name':
                    artifactId = 'my-second-specific-name'
                    break
                default:
                    break
            }

            from components.java
        }
    }
}
```