# Clean way to publish Android Library AAR with external dependencies with maven

Tags: android, maven, gradle, nexus, aar

I am building an Android Library that I am trying to publish to a Nexus Maven Repository. What leaves me puzzled is that there seems to be no clean way of publishing my project through gradle with the `maven-publish` plugin.

I found a number of answers, which don't really satisfy me:

[This plugin](https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin) only works okay-ish and it is not currently maintained.

[Modifying the generated POM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26874498/maven-publish-android-library-with-aar-and-source-jar) in my build.gradle works, I just don't feel like this is the way it should be done - it seems to common of a problem to be solved in each and every android library's `build.gradle`.

Google even mentions the `maven-publish` plugin in their [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#publish_multiple_variants) but they don't really show how to use it.

Please tell me what I am missing: Is the problem less trivial than I think? I am just trying to publish an AAR with a pom stating it's dependency, I am trying to build the most standard and default solution I can.

Thanks in advance.