# How to distribute android sdk publically?

Tags: android, artifacts, jitpack, android-module

I have build SDK with android modules(aar). How to distribute SDK publically.
i.e I want to download this via Gradle build without giving credential

example
   `implementation 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'`

Comment: Have you checked this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26874498/publish-an-android-library-to-maven-with-aar-and-source-jar

Comment: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-setup-private-maven-repository/en i follow this guide to deploy to jfrog artifacts but its require credential to implement sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By following this guide I upload my SDK globally in jcenter()

https://medium.com/swlh/android-library-kotlin-creation-access-deploy-problems-fixes-everything-you-want-to-c1a1701f0e8f

Anyone need help ping me.