# Cannot access class using aar. Using as a module gives no error

Tags: android, dependencies, aar

My app has several modules.

One of these modules is the `ProductsModule`. This module depends on two other modules of my app. Let's call them `ModuleA` and `ModuleB`.

In my app module, I have a class (`ProductsStorage`) and no errors appear if I use `ProductsModule`.

I've then converted `ProductsModule` to an `aar` and use it in my app.
The app compiles normally and then runs normally without errors, but AndroidStudio now shows an error in the `ProductsStorage` class. Again, the app compiles without error and runs normally.

The error is the following:

```
Cannot access class 'my.app.package.model.ProductStock'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
my.app.package.productsmodule.model.ProductDetails public final var productStock: [ERROR : my.app.package.model.ProductStock]
  Gradle: :producs_module:@aar
```

`ProductDetails` is a data class that has `val productStock: ProductStock` as a constructor parameter.

`ProductStock` is a class in `ModuleA`. My app module also has access to `ModuleA`

This happens even if I open my product on different AS versions and invalidate caches does not solve the issue.

How can I make that error disappear? I'm afraid it will have some unexpected behaviour to my app, even if now I cannot see any problem.

Comment: Please check out this answer and see if it works or not. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59534424/9053942 Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks, but all the dependencies that `ProductsModule` has are also implemented by my app module