# How can I copy the source code of projectA into projectB before projectB compiles?

Tags: java, android, groovy, gradle

Having two Gradle projects projectA and projectB where projectA is a dependency of projectB, i.e., my build.gradle of projectB contains:

```
dependencies {
   compile(project(':projectA'))
}
```

How can I copy the source code from projectA into projectB before the java `build` task runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom copy task that copies the source code from project A to project B.

```
task copyProjectA(type: Copy) {
    from project(":projectA").projectDir.toString() + "/src/main/java"
    into project.projectDir.toString() + "/destination"
}

tasks.compileJava.dependsOn += copyProjectA
```

I have a difficult time understanding why you'd want to do that though.

Comment: Do you know how I can create a source jar in projectA and copy this into destination of projectB?

Comment: You can have a task depend on tasks in other projects: `task copyProjectA(type: Copy, dependsOn: project(":projectA").tasks.sourceJar) {`

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474729/how-to-build-sources-jar-with-gradle) for how to build a source JAR.