# How to debug a project in Intellij while setting the breakpoints in another project

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

I have a (Maven-based) project A loaded in Intellij that has a number of dependencies.

I have the source files of one of those dependencies (say B) in another Intellij project.

I would like to put breakpoints in B and debug project A so that A stops when breakpoints are reached in project B.

In Eclipse, I just need to have both projects in the same workspace and it works. Since there are no workspaces in Intellij, I wonder how to do it, and if it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with multiple maven projects, I find it convenient to put both under a parent maven project.  The two child projects are not aware of the parent and remain independent of each other, but by aggregating them on one parent pom, you can conveniently build and test them at the same time, keeping the dependent in sync with its dependency.  When you do that, you can also create Run configurations for each project, launch them in debug mode, and put breakpoints in either or both of them.

The parent pom stays in the parent folder of both projects, and does not need to go into source control because the child poms don't refer to it as their parent--its only for your convenience in working on both at the same time.  Such a pom might look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>anything</groupId>
    <artifactId>anything</artifactId>
    <version>0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>All projects</name>
    <modules>
        <module>project-1-subdirectory</module>
        <module>project-2-subdirectory</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Comment: That's cheating with Intellij, but it does the job!

Comment: I don't think this is cheating, it's the way maven works. I'm super happy I found this post, as my only problem with IntelliJ (coming from NetBeans) so far was that I was unable to open multiple projects simultaneously. This restores that functionality. I am in love!

Comment: I think having projects A and B as modules of the same parent project as suggested by @Hank D is a bit of a hack because it diverts from the original purpose of multi-module maven projects. Besides, what if A or B already has a parent project? I added another answer that is generic and works with maven and gradle projects.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers sound like they would work, but all I had to do was go to:

**Project Structure** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)

**> Modules**

> on the **Sources** tab for the module that has dependencies, look on the right side,

click the **<kbd>+ Add Content Root</kbd>**, then **add** the `src` folder of the dependency project.

I was able to then put breakpoints in those `src` files and IntelliJ would step to them in debugging.

(Note you may see the warning "`Alternative source available for the class ...`")

---

Reference

> From https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html,
>
> "Modules normally have one content root. You can add more content roots. For example, this might be useful if pieces of your code are stored in different locations on your computer."

Comment: The shortcut here is Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S.

Comment: Maybe behavior changed since 2018 but your answer does not fully works for, I actually can put breakpoints on source code (they have the green tick saying they are fine) but when they are reached this is the .class that is opened and I therefore cannot debug step by step, I then put my own answer.

Answer (score 3):

1) Build project B to your `localRepository` *with source* files.

- If B is a maven project, you can use the [source plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/attach-source-javadoc-artifacts.html). Then `mvn install` should generate file B-*version*-sources.jar.
- If B is a gradle project, you can define a [task to generate the sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474729/how-to-build-sources-jar-with-gradle).

2) Open project A on IntelliJ. Project A has a dependency to B, so IntelliJ can see B-*version*-sources.jar. You just need to open the class on B that you want to debug and set the breakpoints. On the IntelliJ editor you will see a little lock symbol that indicates the class is read-only.

(Depending on your IntelliJ version, you may not even need to have the "-sources" in your local repository in step (1) above, because IntelliJ may be able to decompile the classes to the editor and allow you to set breakpoints.)

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Paulo Merson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51678502/11159476) that did no fully worked for me (see my comment in it for more information), but was almost there, I had to go to:

**File** -> **Project Structure...** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)

**> Modules**

> On the **Dependencies** tab for the module that has dependencies, find the dependency for which you want to add sources (you can sort by name to find it easily),

> Right click on it and select "Edit..."

> Click the **<kbd>+</kbd>** button above the "Classes", "Sources" and "JavaDocs" lists (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>), then navigate to the `src` folder of the dependency project.

Now you can add breakpoints and do step by step debugging.