# How to know code usage of projects dependent on current project?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I formerly use eclipse and open many projects in a single work space, for example, I have project A, B and C. Both B and C will be dependent on A, thus when I change code in A, I can get usage information in B and C immediately.

Then I transferred to use IDEA, which is awesome, yet projects are independent and they are dependent in pom declaration, the side effect is I cannot get usage of B and C immediately, I need to open B and C, then build A, and check whether some change such as access level adjustment broke codes in B and C.

So what is the best practice to resolve such issues?

PS: For me it's not good to add B and C as module to A.

Comment: Maven multiproject with the root pom.xml defining dependencies between all your sub-projects is the way to go. You open the main project and see your sub-projects as the modules. See also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/eclipse.html.

Comment: This is a huge cheat, but in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36548401/how-to-debug-a-project-in-intellij-while-setting-the-breakpoints-in-another-proj I describe how to set up a fake pom to aggregate maven projects that have interdependencies, without changing the subproject poms in any way.