# How to create source JAR with Gradle from project files (*.java, *.js, *,xml, etc.)?

Tags: java, gradle, jar, build, archive

I want create a source JAR file from my project with every files (not with class files). Have you any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build sources jar with gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474729/how-to-build-sources-jar-with-gradle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use task `javadocJar` and `sourceJar`

```
task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

artifacts {
    archives javadocJar    
    archives sourcesJar 
}
```