# Build source jar with Gradle Kotlin DSL?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474729/how-to-build-sources-jar-with-gradle) asks how to build a SourceJar with Gradle. How can I do the same with the Gradle Kotlin DSL?

The gradle code would be:

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
    archives javadocJar
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following will work:

```
val sourcesJar by creating(Jar::class) {
    dependsOn(JavaPlugin.CLASSES_TASK_NAME)
    classifier = "sources"
    from(sourceSets["main"].allSource)
}

val javadocJar by creating(Jar::class) {
    dependsOn(JavaPlugin.JAVADOC_TASK_NAME)
    classifier = "javadoc"
    from(tasks["javadoc"])
}

artifacts {
    add("archives", sourcesJar)
    add("archives", javadocJar)
}
```

A complete `build.gradle.kts` would look like this:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.2.71"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
}

tasks {
    val sourcesJar by creating(Jar::class) {
        dependsOn(JavaPlugin.CLASSES_TASK_NAME)
        classifier = "sources"
        from(sourceSets["main"].allSource)
    }

    val javadocJar by creating(Jar::class) {
        dependsOn(JavaPlugin.JAVADOC_TASK_NAME)
        classifier = "javadoc"
        from(tasks["javadoc"])
    }

    artifacts {
        add("archives", sourcesJar)
        add("archives", javadocJar)
    }
}
```

Comment: With Gradle 5.0 the line `from(tasks["javadoc"])` no longer works as it resolves to a `TaskProvider<TaskReportTask>` without any `get(int)` operation

Comment: @BenjaminSchmid, try using `val javadocJar by creating(Jar::class) { val javadoc by tasks;  from(javadoc);  classifier = "javadoc"; }`

Comment: Thanks @madhead : Any idea how to delegate the accompaning `sourceSets["main"]`-call?

Comment: `val main by sourcesets` :)

Comment: @BenjaminSchmid. Ok, it seems to be a problem particularly with multi-module projects. In single-module projects there is an extension in Kotlin DSL — `sourceSets`. But that accessor seems to be not generating in multi-module projects, probably due to a bug. But you can use delegates to get any property (it's like `methodMissing` in Groovy, actually). So here is a trick: `val sourcesJar by tasks.creating(Jar::class) { val sourceSets: SourceSetContainer by project; from(sourceSets["main"].allJava); classifier = "sources"; }`. Though, I don't like it it seems to be working.

Answer (score 26):

With Gradle 5.3.1, this is a little nicer and avoids deprecated API:

```
tasks {    
    val sourcesJar by creating(Jar::class) {
        archiveClassifier.set("sources")
        from(sourceSets.main.get().allSource)
    }

    val javadocJar by creating(Jar::class) {
        dependsOn.add(javadoc)
        archiveClassifier.set("javadoc")
        from(javadoc)
    }

    artifacts {
        archives(sourcesJar)
        archives(javadocJar)
        archives(jar)
    }
}
```

Task `assemble` will create all the artifacts.

Answer (score 15):

As of **Gradle 6.0** this is a much easier and cleaner. All you need to do is:

```
java {
    withSourcesJar()
    withJavadocJar()
}
```

Check out the documentation on the [java extension](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java-extension), and its functions, [withSourcesJar()](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaPluginExtension.html#withSourcesJar--) and [withJavadocJar()](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/JavaPluginExtension.html#withJavadocJar--)

Comment: Expression 'java' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found - if you try to use that in a subprojects block to make it work for subprojects as well.

Comment: Apparently the fix for that is to change it to `configure<JavaPluginExtension> { ... }`

Comment: The Java plugin is not available for android libraries (not compatible last I checked)

Answer (score 4):

All described methods fail with error on **Gradle 6.6**:
`SourceSet with name 'main' not found`

I've found a solution that works:

```
tasks {
    val sourcesJar by creating(Jar::class) {
        archiveClassifier.set("sources")
        from(android.sourceSets.getByName("main").java.srcDirs)
    }

    artifacts {
        archives(sourcesJar)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

With Gradle 5.1 you can do something like this

```
tasks {
    val sourcesJar by registering(Jar::class) {
        classifier = "sources"
        from(sourceSets.main.get().allSource)
        dependsOn(classes)
    }
    val javadocJar by registering(Jar::class) {
        classifier = "javadoc"
        from(javadoc.get().destinationDir)
        dependsOn(javadoc)
    }
}
```