# Gradle 5 Kotlin DSL: Common Tasks & Maven Artifacts in multi-modules projects

Tags: java, maven, gradle, multi-module, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I really would like to appreciate Gradle 5 especially in combination with the new Kotlin DSL, but I’m having a very hard time to get (in my eyes) a very, very simple and common build running with Gradle.

#### Task

**Release a Java library** with several **interdependent submodules** in Maven default directory layout **as high-quality Maven artifacts/repository** in a to-the-point, simple Gradle build (i.e. *DRY*).

Therefore: Have a root project as umbrella which defines & contains all the common configuration (practically all except the real dependencies).

#### My current struggles

I ported my current "results" to [a sample project on Github](https://github.com/bentolor/gradle-maven-multimodule-kotlindsl) and [asked this question in the Gradle forum already](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/painfully-ux-simple-use-case-overly-hard-gradle-5-kotlin-dsl-multi-modules-java-library-with-maven-release/29732).

Currently I'm failing to declare the necessary task to provide standard `-sources` and `-javadoc` artifacts in my *central* build.

For example these three "solutions" which you'll find on looking for a Kotlin DSL based solutions **all do no (longer) work** in a multi-module scenario:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/48070667
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/52596969/1237653
- and even the offical ["Maven Publish" documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:complete_example)  is only working in a single-module scenario.

#### Incomplete solution (`/build.gradle.kts`)

Complete example see on Github: https://github.com/bentolor/gradle-maven-multimodule-kotlindsl

```
subprojects {
    apply(plugin = "java-library")
    apply(plugin = "maven-publish")
    group = "de.bentolor.sampleproject"
    version = "0.1.0"

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        // Dependencies used in EVERY module
        "compile"("commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2")
        "testImplementation"("junit:junit:4.12")
    }

    tasks {
        // not working
        /*register("sourcesJar", Jar::class.java) {
            from(sourceSets.main.get().allJava)
            classifier = "sources"
        }*/

       // not working, eiher
       /* task<Jar>("sourcesJar") {
            from(sourceSets.main.get().allJava)
            classifier = "sources"
       } */
    }

    configure<JavaPluginExtension> {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    configure<PublishingExtension> {
        publications {
            create<MavenPublication>(project.name) {
                from(components["java"])
                // won't work, beause inaccessible declaration in `tasks{}`-Block
                //add("archives", javadocJar)
                //add("archives", sourcesJar)
            }
        }

        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
        }
    }
}
```

#### Example submodule `/module2/build.gradle.kts`

```
group = "de.bentolor.sampleproject.module2"

dependencies {
    compile(project(":module1"))
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
subprojects {
    apply<JavaLibraryPlugin>()
    apply<MavenPublishPlugin>()

    group = "de.bentolor.sampleproject"
    version = "0.1.0"

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        val implementation by configurations
        val testImplementation by configurations

        implementation("commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2")
        testImplementation("junit:junit:4.12")
    }

    // This will work, but as long as these tasks are need only for publishing you can declare them inplace later where you need 
    // tasks {
    //     val sourcesJar by creating(Jar::class) {
    //         val sourceSets: SourceSetContainer by project
    //         from(sourceSets["main"].allJava)
    //         classifier = "sources"
    //     }
    //     val javadoc by getting(Javadoc::class)
    //     val javadocJar by creating(Jar::class) {
    //         from(javadoc)
    //         classifier = "javadoc"
    //     }
    // }

    configure<JavaPluginExtension> {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    configure<PublishingExtension> {
        publications {
            create<MavenPublication>(project.name) {
                from(components["java"])

                // If you configured them before
                // val sourcesJar by tasks.getting(Jar::class)
                // val javadocJar by tasks.getting(Jar::class)

                val sourcesJar by tasks.creating(Jar::class) {
                    val sourceSets: SourceSetContainer by project

                    from(sourceSets["main"].allJava)
                    classifier = "sources"
                }
                val javadocJar by tasks.creating(Jar::class) {
                    from(tasks.get("javadoc"))
                    classifier = "javadoc"
                }

                artifact(sourcesJar)
                artifact(javadocJar)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A few notes:

- Why use `String`-based `apply`, when you can do a type-safe `apply<T>()`?
- Why use invokes on stings in `dependencies`, when you can use delegates, which is less hacky and better refactorable.
- Consider using [`implementation` instead of `compile`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation)

Why `sourceSets` is not working in a multi-module project?

When you're using Kotlin DSL it generates accessors for projects based on the applied plugins. It's a two-step process: first Gradle processes plugins (that's why it's recommended to put them in `plugins` block) and generates accessors and then you can use them in your code (accessors are generated as Kotlin extensions for `Project`, `NamedDomainObjectContainer` and so on). But if you're configuring subprojects there are two issues:

- Parent project evaluates before child, so the extensions for child are not known in parent.
- The set of plugins applied to parent and child is different and you need to use children accessors in parent.

`sourceSets` is one of the accessors generated by Kotlin DSL for children. And it's just not available in parent. You can try it yourself: apply only `java` plugin in `subprojects`. `sourceSets` will be available in children build scripts, but not in parent.

This is also why you can use `java` in children, but have to use `configure<JavaPluginExtension>` when configuring it in parent.

But you can use delegates to get references for domain objects, like tasks, source sets, configuration and so on.