# Use code from test package in different module's tests

Tags: gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a 'base' project in kotlin which configured with gradle dsl.
Inside base I have module 'app' and module 'library'.
Module app uses module library.
I want to access module library's tests from module app's tests (to be precise library's testUtils package).

app.build gradle file has the line `implementation(project(":library"))` and like that I can't access library's tests in my main code which is good, but I can't access it from app's tests either.

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144325/gradle-test-dependency)) (possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644011/multi-project-test-dependencies-with-gradle)) where the relevant groovy code is:

```
task testJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: testClasses) {
    baseName = "test-${project.archivesBaseName}"
    from sourceSets.test.output
}

configurations {
    tests
}

artifacts {
    tests testJar
}
```

but I couldn't implement it in gradle dsl.

Also I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52596968/build-source-jar-with-gradle-kotlin-dsl) where the code is:

```
tasks {
    val sourcesJar by creating(Jar::class) {
        dependsOn(JavaPlugin.CLASSES_TASK_NAME)
        classifier = "sources"
        from(sourceSets["main"].allSource)
    }

    val javadocJar by creating(Jar::class) {
        dependsOn(JavaPlugin.JAVADOC_TASK_NAME)
        classifier = "javadoc"
        from(tasks["javadoc"])
    }

    artifacts {
        add("archives", sourcesJar)
        add("archives", javadocJar)
    }
}
```

I need somehow to add `testImplementation` not only with library's source code but with library's tests so that in app's tests I would be able to use library's test packages and in app's source code I wouldn't be able to use library's tests.

Thank you.

Update:

base.build:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile
import java.time.Duration

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.21"
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply(plugin = "kotlin")
    dependencies {
        implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    }
    tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    tasks.withType<Test> {
        useJUnitPlatform()

        // Make sure tests don't take over 10 minutes
        timeout.set(Duration.ofMinutes(10))
    }
}
```

base.settings:

```
import java.net.URI

rootProject.name = "base"

sourceControl {
    gitRepository(URI("https://github.com/path-to-github.git")) {
        producesModule("path.to.package:primitive-storage-layer")
    }
}

include("library")
include("app")
```

app.build:

```
plugins {
    application
}

application {
    mainClassName = "path.to.package.MainKt"
}

val junitVersion = "5.5.0-M1"
val hamkrestVersion = "1.7.0.0"
val mockkVersion = "1.9.3"

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":library"))

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$junitVersion")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:$junitVersion")
    testImplementation("com.natpryce:hamkrest:$hamkrestVersion")
    testImplementation("io.mockk:mockk:$mockkVersion")

    runtime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$junitVersion")
}
```

library.build:

```
val primitiveLibraryVersion = "1.0"
val gsonVersion = "2.8.5"
val junitVersion = "5.5.0-M1"
val mockkVersion = "1.9.3"

dependencies {
    implementation("path.to.package:primitive-storage-layer:$primitiveLibraryVersion")
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:$gsonVersion")

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$junitVersion")
    testImplementation("io.mockk:mockk:$mockkVersion")
}
```

Comment: Can you share your current gradle files?

Comment: @dbramwell added gradle files

Answer (score 1):

Although it would be possible to produce an artifact containing tests and then use that from another project, I'd avoid that and instead refactor the test utilities into a separate subproject (something like `${app}-test-kit`), putting code into *main* sourceset, and then depend on that subproject from both app and library `testImplementation` configurations.

This gives you a cleaner separation and it's more obvious as to what is shared and why.