# Eclipse Open Declaration does not work for Ant project

Tags: eclipse, ant, alfresco

My eclipse is **Indigo** version. Open declaration works in creating new java projects in my elipse.

But in the case, I get alfresco source code of the whole project(assumed as root) from the svn and root is composed of many java projects. It is built with `ant` i.e. by running `build.xml` to build jar from each java project and finally create a war file and deploy. 
In this project, open declaration F3 and open type Hierarchy F4 does not work.
It is said

> The resource is not on the build path of a Java Project.

---

So I take another workspae and import these java projects inside root one after another. Open declaration F3 and open type Hierarchy F4 works. But this workspace is just to see source file and does not work.

**I want to know what is the reason of F3 and F4 does not work and can you explain how to fix it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the JAR files to the build path of your project and then attach source to them.

Right click on your project in the Package Explorer or Navigator and select the Java Build Path:

[image: Use 'Add External JARs...' to add JAR files]

Click on 'Add External JARs...' to add JAR files. The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122160/is-there-an-easy-way-to-attach-source-in-eclipse) provide info on how to attach source to the JARs.