# Could not configure konakart shopping - cart

Tags: eclipse, gwt, shopping-cart, konakart

How to import and configure konakart shopping-cart source code in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Not only GWT project for any java project the process is the same .

Here you can find a [Documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-importproject.htm) by `Eclipse` to import an existing project in to your workspace

For [attaching source](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2011/08/attaching-java-source-with-eclipse-ide/)  in Eclipse  :[Is there an easy way to attach source in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122160/is-there-an-easy-way-to-attach-source-in-eclipse)

To do the task first you have to download the `*src.zip *` of the corresponding project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Baadshah. but i need to run the build.xml file using command line, to get the working code and that doesn't work for me. It shows some 'could not find file' error.

Comment: Smells like path problem.cross check it.

Answer (score 0):

In KonaKart there is an ANT task that you can run to create the Eclipse project:

Go to the custom directory under your installation, then:

```
C:\Program Files\KonaKart\custom>bin\kkant -p
Buildfile: build.xml

Main targets:

make_eclipse_project   Create an Eclipse Project for Developing the Struts-2 Storefront
```

So you would enter:

```
C:\Program Files\KonaKart\custom>bin\kkant make_eclipse_project
```