# debug external library project

Tags: java, eclipse

My Java project I run on Eclipse uses external jar library. Now, for better understanding I need to trace jar library code. Library source code I have, but how to tell my project not to look to defined in "Java Build Path" jar, but to source I have.

Library source is developed not with Eclipse.

Comment: Google Eclipse attach JAR sources. You find nice stuff like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122160/is-there-an-easy-way-to-attach-source-in-eclipse)

Comment: Like ppeterka said, you can configure the source path in the "Configure Build Path" window.