# why i cannot look into the source code from "JCE"

Tags: java, eclipse

Does anybody knows why i cannot look into the source code of "Cipher" in eclipse? the source code is there and i can see some other build-in source code from openjdk such as "println" but cannot figure out the reason why i cannot view the source code of "Cipher" and other JCE class. I download the source package from grepcode website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach source for that particular JAR. ctrl+click on any method which is implemented in that JAR, click on attach source from newly opened window. Give the SRC path of that JAR. This should do the trick for you.

[Source](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-properties-source-attachment.htm) and [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122160/is-there-an-easy-way-to-attach-source-in-eclipse).

Comment: i should have tried the approach you mentioned, as i said in this thread, i can see the implementation for some build-in method from jdk in eclipse but weird enough I cannot view some jce implementation. the fact is the source code have already in the source jar i have attached.

Comment: Adding jars in build path may help then.