# Jersey ClientBuilder.newClient(): source not found

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, jersey

I have an Java 64-bit Eclipse application with Eclipse running on Windows 7 Pro x64.

I downloaded the [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net) bundle, jaxrs-ri-2.7.zip, for client RESTful API access.

I added these external jars (Project | Build Path | Configure Build Path... | Libraries):

```
jaxrs-ri/api/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar
jaxrs-ri/lib/jersey-client.jar
jaxrs-ri/lib/jersey-common.jar
```

Here is the source:

```
package prjTestJersey;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Client oClient = ClientBuilder.newClient();

        oClient.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I receive the following error, when stepping over the first line, Clinet oClient...:

```
Source not found.
```

Why the error and how do I fix it? Why "source not found" instead of a real error.

Note: I tried copying the 3 jar files to the project's lib folder, but that did not do any good. I am using the Eclipse debugger, so pressing F11 in debug view and then doing an F6 over the line.

UPDATE:

I tried creating a brand new 32-bit application (WindowBuilder SWT application window) and simply updated main(...), and same problem. That means the problem is platform independent.

UPDATE 2:

The posted answer to try running was not a bad idea. :-) That gave another clue, which I have to track down. Here is the dump.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/hk2/utilities/binding/AbstractBinder
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig.<init>(ClientConfig.java:452)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder.<init>(JerseyClientBuilder.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.ws.rs.client.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:116)
    at javax.ws.rs.client.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:206)
    at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newBuilder(ClientBuilder.java:86)
    at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient(ClientBuilder.java:114)
    at AppMain.main(AppMain.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 12 more
```

FINAL ANSWER:
(Thanks to both answers for the help.)

I was missing dependencies. The needed list is:

```
swt_win32_x86.jar
api/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar
ext/jersey-guava-2.7.jar
ext/hk2-api-2.2.0.jar
lib/jersey-common.jar
lib/jersey-client.jar
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that "Source not found" simply is a message from Eclipse telling you it cannot debug into `Client oClient = ClientBuilder.newClient();` as you do not have the source code for the three jars attached in Eclipse. If you just run the program (without debugging) it might very well work. Read more here on how to add source code to jar files in Eclipse: [Is there an easy way to attach source in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122160/is-there-an-easy-way-to-attach-source-in-eclipse).

If it still doesn't work, I would suggest adding **all** the jars from the bundle you downloaded to make sure you aren't missing some dependency.

Comment: Adding in every possible jar resolved the issue. I just have to find out which jar now, then I will mark your answer as the answer. The Jersey documentation is quite poor. Thanks!

Comment: Based on your additions to the question, it seems you are missing the HK2 libs (for dependency injection). Add `hk2-api-2.2.0.jar`, `hk2-locator-2.2.0.jar` and `hk2-utils-2.2.0.jar` to get those (they might in turn depend on some of the other jars, you really want to use some kind of dependency resolution hanlding this for you such as gradle/maven).

Comment: I was missing two jars "ext/jersey-guava-2.7.jar" and "ext/hk2-api-2.2.0.jar". Yes, I need to add on some sort of dependency checker/adder to Eclipse.

Answer (score 10):

You are missing the hk2 api jar which contains the class org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.hk2/hk2-api

Comment: ext/jersey-guava-2.7.jar and ext/hk2-api-2.2.0.jar, might as well just add everything in ext, as I will be doing get/post/pull/delete, but we shall see.

Comment: This should be the correct answer to this question.

Answer (score 6):

> Only for gradle users.

Right version of `javax.ws.rs-api` and `jersey-client` will resolve the class not found issue.

```
compile group: 'javax.ws.rs', name: 'javax.ws.rs-api', version: '2.1-m01'
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core', name: 'jersey-client', version: '2.24.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add below dependency it will resolve the issue**

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
  <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```