# How do I attach the actual implementation Java code of a class in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have inherited a project that uses calls to an existing jar. The former programmer have had the fortune of obtaining a/the source code of the jar. However the construction is rather complex. I use an abstract class, say Size. In the source code I find an implementation of that class, say SizeProxy. It has an object of class SizeImplementation and any calls on Size.getInfo() will be implemented as a call to this.theSize.getInfo().

In short I have managed to find the actual implementation of getInfo that actually does anything interesting. I would love to make it possible to go from "my" code o_size.getInfo() and go directly to the "implementation" in SizeImplementation.getInfo. Right now I can't make Eclipse do that, possibly because the class names don't match. Please help!

Comment: Would I be correct in saying you want to look at the source code for a compiled library? Is so what you want is a decompiler. It won't give you back the true original source code but will give you a close approximation (java is quite good for this) unless the original developer has taken steps to prevent this (obfuscation)

Comment: No, I have the source code. The setup is somewhat convoluted with interfaces and abstract classes AND a class Size that holds an object o_size of class SizeImplementation and the method in Size getInfo() is simply a call to this.o_size.getInfo() but I "know" where the interesting code that actually does any work is and I want to link my call to getInfo() to that implementation code.

Comment: O I see, I don't think that's possible because an interface can have more than 1 implementation and an abstact class can be extended by more than 1 child class; which you are using is generally not known at compile time except in very simple cases. Of course you can usually go indirectly. I use netbeans and that lets you go from an interface to implemeting classes . I imagine eclipse is similar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122160/is-there-an-easy-way-to-attach-source-in-eclipse

Comment: Are you able to get to the source via many steps within eclipse? (navigate to interface --> navigate to abstract class --> navigate to implementation); in which case see my answer. Or do you have to look at external files in a text editor. In which case see Vivart's comment

Answer (score 0):

This is in general not possible because an interface can have several implementations, and an abstract class (or any class) can be extended by many classes. Take this example

```
public void doSomething(boolean option){
    List<String> someList;
    if (option){
         list=new ArrayList<>();
    }else{
         list=new LinkedList<>();
    }

    list.add("Where do I go"); 

}
```

Were you to attempt to go to the implementing source directly from `list.add("Where do I go");` to the implementation of `.add()` where would you end up? ArrayList's or LinkedList's.

This is why you have to go via the interface or abstract class then choose your implemetation from there