# Every Class File from LWJGL has no source

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl

I just installed LWJGL and I selected lwjgl.jar, it loaded all the classes but when i click on one, it just says "This class has no source" Please help!

Comment: The source is available on their website man.

Comment: You need to add the source to the jar in the classpath. download the src zip file then add it to the LWJGL jar file. if you need more help I'll answer in the Bottom Peace

Comment: Thanks, I am very new to LWJGL so I don't know exactly how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

How to add the source to a jar is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122160/is-there-an-easy-way-to-attach-source-in-eclipse),
but note that you won't need to do this to use the classes in the jar. The source and javadoc attachments are only useful for development and debugging.