# onActivityResult works!! but i can't debug

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

The app works when i run it normally
But when i put a breakpoint and run it eclipse pop up window with this content:

> source attachment does not contain the source for the file
>   dexfile.class

[image]

Comment: can you supply a screenshot where you put the breakpoint. This sounds like you put it at a weird place.

Comment: The file you are trying to access is out of your project scope. You wont be able to see its code and debug steps inside it unless you have its code attached.

Comment: I m just start a "startActivityForResult" to another activity and get back the info in :onActivityResult" and my breakpoint is in the onActivityResult.

Answer (score 1):

Attach the Android source code to your build path, so you can see the java code in the debugger.

Instructions here: [Is there an easy way to attach source in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122160/is-there-an-easy-way-to-attach-source-in-eclipse)