# Running into JDK files from Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, java-7, jdk1.7

I develop software on **Eclipse Mars IDE**, under MS Windows 10 OS, based on **Java v7**. And now I've got some configuration problems related to the IDE. What I want, is that to run into JDK source code from the IDE once I click on the 'step into' (or in other way). I've included the 'src.zip' on the path in the way provided by the IDE. Yet, when I attempt to run into the source code, the IDE says the 'source code not found'.
I want this feature in order to be able to debug some things related to my current app.

Regards

Comment: what 'way provided' did you try?

Comment: So, I run the IDE and select 'step into' on SDK's method. Then the IDE throws a window which says ' Execution did not enter ' values()'  befor the current method returned'. Then it shows a message saying ' source not found', and gives a button to locate the source code on the path. That is were I have passed in the src.zip archive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to attach source in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122160/is-there-an-easy-way-to-attach-source-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set this through the Java->Installed JRE's found in Eclipse -> Window ->Preferences. See screen shot below.

[image]