# Class file editor : Source not found error for ILock, ClassPathSuite classes

Tags: junit, package, hazelcast

I am getting **Class file editor : Source not found error** for the classes in **junit / hazelcast** packages. Previously i got this error for all built in java classes. But after adding the Source zip file, i am able to see String.class and all. What i need to do for these classes. Please find the screenshot 
[image]

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly enough, your question contains **all** the concepts you need to know in order to answer it.

In order for your IDE to show you source code for **any** library you are using, the corresponding library needs to come with source code attached to it.

In other words: you managed to point your IDE to the ZIP file containing the source code for your JRE/JDK - thus your IDE knows what to show you when want to open up String.class

Now it seems that you are using other libraries as well. Maybe maybe, other libraries, have other, different source code ZIP files?!

Long story short: you need to add "source code" ZIPs for each and any additional library you are using and that you want to "peek into".

Within eclipse, you achieve that for example as described in [that SO q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122160/is-there-an-easy-way-to-attach-source-in-eclipse). Side note: that is also something to keep in mind: you should do prior research before coming up with "new" questions. Especially when you are a beginner, you can be very sure that "your" question was asked here before.

Comment: thank you @Jägermeister. i have a jar which is in my project. How to include them in src.zip ? or i should create a new zip file and i need to add?