# Unable to open jar file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, decompiler

I am unable to open jar files in eclipse. For example:

**public class HttpSessionAndContextExa extends HttpServlet**

if I want to see HttpServlet class it show me following error:

javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc   could be found. Please help.

Comment: possible duplication of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122160/is-there-an-easy-way-to-attach-source-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution. The issue is due to we have not added tomcat source file for servlet in eclipse:

1. right click on project -> prefrences -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> add external jar - > add servlet-api.jar(in var/lib/tomcat/lib)
2. Then add java decopiler in your eclipse with market place.
   Help->eclipse marketplace->search “JadClipse” ->install
3. apply decompiler:
   window->prefrences->serach “decompiler” ->Apply

Comment: This was a quick answer (0:  (you can mark your answer as accepted so others know that it solved your problem)