# How to change Eclipse .class view without having sources

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

I have a little problem with displaying compiled java classes. In Eclipse the view looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeRr9.png

But in Netbeans looks like this ( better for me with compiled code message):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpYtf.png

Is there is a possibility to change the view to look like in NetBeans?

Edit:
Without adding source ! Because I know that I can add source.

Comment: See [another post for details on this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14649805/5503404). You just need to attach the source.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to attach source in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122160/is-there-an-easy-way-to-attach-source-in-eclipse)

Comment: No, because I don't want to add any source.

Comment: Without attaching source there is no way to improve this in standard Eclipse. You may be able to find some addon plugin to improve things such as https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/enhanced-class-decompiler

Comment: LOL, kindly, man you are asking like "I want to build the car, but without the wheels"- answer is simple- you cant.. 
Only way, which can you do is to look for some decompiler plugin, but it will not be exact code which you are expecting

Comment: No. I want to change the look/view of the compiled class. Look at NetBeans screenshot.

Comment: In Window/Preferences/General/Editors/File Associations, you can associate the class files with a decompiler, if you have one in you eclipse install. But I don't know if it's possible to change how the default eclipse class file viewer display the class.