# How to build an executable uber-jar also containing source files?

Tags: java, maven, uberjar

have a little java-Project in Eclipse with maven that I would like to turn into a jar with the following specifications:

- executable
- containing all dependencies
- containing all source files (*.java) besides the compiled *.class files

So far, I've found shade and source  as plugin which each serve two of my needs but not all three. Does anyone know how to tweak maven into doing all of the above?

I'm aware of this being an usual request but the goal is to have the source code with the class files in case something goes wrong and nobody remembers which project this came from.

Comment: You dont - sources are kept in separate jar.

Answer (score 0):

Including the sources has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122160/is-there-an-easy-way-to-attach-source-in-eclipse)

Regarding an executable jar with all the libraries included in a single file, what you're looking for is a fat jar. You can use [this plugin](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/) for eclipse or [Maven to build](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/create-a-fat-jar-file-maven-assembly-plugin/) your jar.

Comment: Shade provides said fat jar / uberjars this but still doesn't solve the initial problem. Been through the list of plugins but am hoping for someone know happens to know a little twist.